# How to reference a nested map in a generic fashion

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to access a nested field like the `services` key for example from a yaml file I unmarshalled. For what it's worth I don't want to have to build a `struct` that reflects the structure of the yaml file since it may not always take this form. The yaml file looks like the following:

```
declared-services:
    Cloudant:
        label: cloudantNoSQLDB
        plan: Lite
applications:
- name: myProject
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  random-route: true
  buildpack: java
  services:
  - Cloudant
  timeout: 180
env:
  services_autoconfig_excludes: cloudantNoSQLDB=config
```

The code looks like this

```
import "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

func getManifestConfig() *Manifest {
    wd, _ := os.Getwd()
    manPath := wd + "/JavaProject/" + manifest
    var man map[string]interface{}
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(manPath)
    if err != nil {
        e(err) //irrelevant method that prints error messages
    }

    yaml.Unmarshal(f, &man)
    fmt.Println(man["applications"]) //This will print all the contents under applications 
    fmt.Println(man["applications"].(map[string]interface{})["services"]) //panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your intent is to use a mapping for `applications`. If so, delete the "-" following the text "applications:":

```
declared-services:
    Cloudant:
        label: cloudantNoSQLDB
        plan: Lite
applications:
  name: myProject
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  random-route: true
  buildpack: java
  services:
  - Cloudant
  timeout: 180
env:
  services_autoconfig_excludes: cloudantNoSQLDB=config
```

Access the `applications` field as a `map[interface{}]interface{}`:

```
fmt.Println(man["applications"].(map[interface{}]interface{})["services"])
```

A good way to debug issues like this is to print the value with "%#v":

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", man["applications"])
// output with the "-"
// []interface {}{map[interface {}]interface {}{"buildpack":"java", "services":[]interface {}{"Cloudant"}, "timeout":180, "name":"myProject", "memory":"512M", "instances":1, "random-route":true}}

// output without the "-":
// map[interface {}]interface {}{"instances":1, "random-route":true, "buildpack":"java", "services":[]interface {}{"Cloudant"}, "timeout":180, "name":"myProject", "memory":"512M"}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[interface {}]interface {}` runtime error @Cerise Limón

Comment: thx that fixed it, how would you fix the the panic I referenced in my comment. Is there a good way?

Comment: Use `fmt.Println(man["applications"].([]interface{})[0].(map[interface{}]interface{})["services"])` to avoid the panic using the YAML text shown in the question.